# redirecting webpage programmatically

Tags: html

I have a feedback page in my website. In my website's homepage, when someone clicks on 'Feedback', it will open a modal window to ask a human verification question. If the response is correct, i want to programatically open the url to my feedback page.

My concerns is:
The feedback page should not be accessible by directly entering the url,i.e., www.mysite\feedback.html. How can i prevent this from opening my feedback page?

I'm also aware that my anti-spamming effort isnt the best option, but for now i dont need a robust mechanism.

Any solution?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just put the CAPTCHA on your feedback page?

If that's not an option you need to use sessions to store the "captcha passed" flag and check for it on the contact page (also in your server-side code). After successfully submitting the form you need to clear the flag so someone cannot spam manually after completing just a single captcha.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to access the Referrer header of the request in your web platform. You can check this value to see if the referrer is from a page you accept. If not, you can return a 403 or whatever response, and if so, you can return the actual page. You will need access to a server-side framework, such as PHP or ASP.NET. Note, however, that it is easy to create HTTP requests and spoof the Referrer header.